# How to detect every mouse event in system using java

Tags: mouse, eventhandler

How to detect every mouse event in system using java?

I have tried using Point class to catch mouse motion but that thing was not so convenient.

Comment: Please provide more details like what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import org.jnativehook.GlobalScreen;
import org.jnativehook.NativeHookException;
import org.jnativehook.keyboard.NativeKeyEvent;
import org.jnativehook.keyboard.NativeKeyListener;

class GlobalKeyListenerExample implements NativeKeyListener {
    public void nativeKeyPressed(NativeKeyEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Key Pressed: " +         NativeKeyEvent.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode()));

            if (e.getKeyCode() == NativeKeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE) {
            }
    }

    public void nativeKeyReleased(NativeKeyEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Key Released: " + NativeKeyEvent.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode()));
    }

    public void nativeKeyTyped(NativeKeyEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Key Typed: " + e.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode()));
    }
    public GlobalKeyListenerExample()
    {
        try {
                    GlobalScreen.registerNativeHook();
            }
            catch (NativeHookException ex) {
                    System.err.println("There was a problem registering the native hook.");
                    System.err.println(ex.getMessage());

                    System.exit(1);
            }
        GlobalScreen.getInstance().addNativeKeyListener(this);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            try {
                    GlobalScreen.registerNativeHook();
            }
            catch (NativeHookException ex) {
                    System.err.println("There was a problem registering the native hook.");
                    System.err.println(ex.getMessage());

                    System.exit(1);
            }

            //Construct the example object and initialze native hook.
            GlobalScreen.getInstance().addNativeKeyListener(new GlobalKeyListenerExample());
    }
```

}